# Property Observer in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, didset, property-observer

Any idea how I can return a UIView from within didSet ?

I have a method that returns a UIView.
I need to observe an Int and return a UIView as the Int changes. I have a didSet observer set, however, I get an error when trying to return the UIView.

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

```
func newUIView() -> UIView {

   var newUIView = UIView()

   return newUIView
}

var observingValue: Int = someOtherValue {
       didSet {
             //Xcode complains whether I use return or not
            return func newUIView()          
        }
}
```

Comment: `observingValue` is of type `Int`, so why in the WORLD would `didSet` for the value `observingValue` of type `Int` return `newUIView()` which returns type `UIView`? Additionally, that `func` and `return` words are not placed correctly... You don't place a `return` within `didSet`...TLDR: Why did you return a `UIView` for a value of type `Int`?...Much less, `return`ing within a `didSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in a comment:

> I guess my struggle is how to observe that value and react (update UI) to it accordingly

An observer is a perfectly good way to do that. But you don't *return* something; you *call* something. This is a very, very common pattern in Swift iOS Cocoa programming:

```
var myProperty : MyType {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}
func updateUI() {
    // update the UI based on the properties
}
```

At the time that the `didSet` code runs, `myProperty` has already been changed, so the method `updateUI` can fetch it and use it to update the interface.

Comment: This nails it! The problem is my "func updateUI() -> UIView" returns a UIView, so I can't call it from didSet. That's what led me to ask the question in the first place

Comment: Well, obviously you need to architect your interface updating code in such a way that a property observer _can_ call into it. I don't know why your `updateUI` thinks it's a good idea to return a value, but the point is, the property observer is not going to return anything; it is just going to kick off the interface updating mechanism.

Comment: Matt, props to you for divining the OPs intent from the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking doesn't make any sense.

A didSet is a block of code you add to an instance variable that gets invoked when anybody changes the value of that variable. There is no place to return anything.

If you need code that changes an instance variable and returns a view, you need to write a function:

```
func updateObservingValue(newValue: Int) -> UIView {
   observingValue = newValue
   return newUIView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It made not sense to me either. I just thought I was missing something. I guess my struggle is how to observe that value and react (update UI) to it accordingly.

Comment: Matt understood what you were trying to do and pointed you in the right direction.